# How to crop or resize Image to set aspect ratio in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crop, image-resizing

I have an image control in my webform. I set its width 100px and height 100px. but if someone upload an image of ratio 100 * 120. I want it crop or resize and set 100 * 100. I tried to set max width but not worked , I tried bitmap method with code

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string filename = FileUpload1.FileName;
        string directory = Server.MapPath("~/");
        Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(FileUpload1.FileContent);
        float origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
        float origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
        float sngRatio = origWidth / origHeight;
        float newWidth = 100;
        float newHeight = newWidth / sngRatio;
        Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP,Convert.ToInt32(newWidth),Convert.ToInt32(newHeight));
        Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);
        oGraphics.SmoothingMode=System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        oGraphics.InterpolationMode=System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        newBMP.Save(directory + filename);
        originalBMP = null;
        newBMP = null;
        oGraphics = null;
        Label1.Text = "File <b style='color: red;'>" + filename + "&lt;</b> uploaded.";
        Image1.ImageUrl = @"~/" + filename;
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "No file uploaded!";
    }
}
```

it worked but it save the resized image in directery I want to save original image in directory and display the resize image in image control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Web Image Resize handler on codeplex : http://webimageresizer.codeplex.com/

It is a custom handler to process images.

**Sample urls**
*Taken from the codeplex project's home page*

// Returns the image mapping to /bla.jpg resized to width of 100 pixels preserving aspect relative to height
/ImageHandler.ashx?src=/bla.jpg&width=100

// Returns the image mapping to /bla.jpg resized to height of 100 pixels preserving aspect relative to width
/ImageHandler.ashx?src=/bla.jpg&height=100

// Returns the image mapping to /bla.jpg resized to width 100 pixels and a height of 50 pixels
/ImageHandler.ashx?src=/bla.jpg&width=100&height=50

**Another option is to use http://imageresizing.net/**

The benefit is that it registers a handler to handle images transparently, meaning, that you only add querystring variables to your original image url to manipulate the image.

**Sample urls**

/images/bla.jpg?h=100&w=100

Comment: thanks for answering jaq i just trying image resizing.net thanks for sample urls

Comment: sample url of /images/bla.jpg?h=100&w=100 wont work can you edit please

Comment: `Image1.ImageUrl = @"~/" + filename + "?h=100&w=100";` is probably what you're after, as this will generate the relative url to the image and add the width and height querystring variables.